# QR scan swapping characters

Tags: javascript, post, encoding

I am currently working with a QR made with qrcode https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/

But I have trouble while reading it.

The content of the QR is checked before sending and is a JWT token like this one:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ7XCJ0YXJqZXRhXCI6XCIqKioqNCoqKioqKioqKlwiLFwibm9tXCI6XCIqKioqKioqKioqKioqKlwifSIsImlhdCI6MTY4NjMwODcwODk5MX0.IajSQzRdC3PkxI4opTbwk-bqcCE-75z9whYQwt5Z2nFwVLGjHZRbTcjC1dy-jyTpPbVsWimQU96jxynopepCXQ
```

But when i scan my QR what is being send in the network is the same token but swapping the '-' with '

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ7XCJ0YXJqZXRhXCI6XCIqKioqNCoqKioqKioqKlwiLFwibm9tXCI6XCIqKioqKioqKioqKioqKlwifSIsImlhdCI6MTY4NjMwODcwODk5MX0.IajSQzRdC3PkxI4opTbwk'bqcCE'75z9whYQwt5Z2nFwVLGjHZRbTcjC1dy'jyTpPbVsWimQU96jxynopepCXQ
```

This make us unable to decode our token so i would like to know two thing:

1. Why is this happening?
2. What would be the best approach to solve it.

Thanks.

EDIT 1: UPDATE

If i can the QR with a different app, like my mobile app the qr I can read the qr in the right way so the problem is not in the QR but in the way that they read the QR and send it to the backEnd. I will delete the JWT and QR-Code TAGS.

Comment: I would guess an encoding issue somewhere in the chain. Codepages and friends can lead to many interesting results. But - try to post an image of the offending code generated. Makes it simpler to evalueate.

Comment: @MyICQ well, i have been trying some more and is definetly an encoding issue of that website in particular, if i scan my qrcode with my mobile app it works fine so the trouble is that when they read it and send it to the Backend they are not encoding it right. As for the image, for security reasons i can not post it as it would have sensitive data (and if i generate it using a different way, it would lost it´s purpose.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with our provider it seems like the problem is not in the code but in the configuration of the different QR scanners they where trying to use, to be more exact, some of the QR scans they are currently using don´t work with UTF-8 but with other ISO that doesn´t allow some special characters.

This make impossible for them to decode a QR code if when coding it we have special characters.

The easiest solution is to encode the JWT in base 64 to avoid the need to check every QR scanner

Comment: Instead of base64 you could simply use another encoding like latin1 since there is no special characters in a JWT anyways. The JWT complies to this regex [a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+ so any basic encoding could do.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that some of those scanners are unable to read "-" or "_". I don´t usually work with them so i don´t know why but i thought that it would be easier if we try with just a base64 which they can easily decode an obtain the JWT

Comment: Well, if your solution works... It's just adding a step since you'll have to convert to base64.

Comment: Yeah, but i thinks it´s better to do it in the software level than to check every scanner to check if they work right. The problem is that i can not control both ends, so even if it´s not the cleanest solution, is the fastest one to implement